# Django Formset populating when it should be blank

Tags: django, django-forms

My goal is to have a formset that lists 5 versions of the same form. On submit the form should create the filled out forms in the DB.

My issue is that the forms come repopulated with data. Which is bad. Any thoughts on what I might be doing wrong?

**Models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

PRIORITIES = (
    ('1', 'High'),
    ('2', 'Medium'),
    ('3', 'Low'),
)

class Todo(models.Model):
    task = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    priority = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=PRIORITIES)
    creation_date = models.DateField('date created', blank=True, null=True)
    due_date = models.DateField('date due', blank=True, null=True)
    completion_date = models.DateField('date complete', blank=True, null=True)
    completed = models.BooleanField()
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.task
```

**Forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from pooflinger.todo.models import Todo
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.forms.models import modelformset_factory

TodoFormSet = modelformset_factory(Todo, max_num=2,)

class TodoForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Todo
```

**Views.py**

```
def todo_form(request):
    user = request.user
    current_date = datetime.now()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = TodoFormSet(request.POST)
        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/todo/')
    else:
        formset = TodoFormSet()
    return render_to_response('todo/todo_formset.html', {
        'user': user,
        'formset': formset,
        'current_date': current_date,
    }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**form template**

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <table>
        {{ formset }}
    </table>
        <button class="glue primary" type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button></p>

</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

apollo13 on irc django channel figured out the answer.

I need to add a queryset

**Edits**

```
qs = Todo.objects.none()
formset = TodoFormSet(queryset=qs)
```

**Final code**

```
def todo_form(request):
    user = request.user
    current_date = datetime.now()
    qs = Todo.objects.none()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = TodoFormSet(request.POST)
        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/todo/')
    else:
        formset = TodoFormSet(queryset=qs)
    return render_to_response('todo/todo_formset.html', {
        'user': user,
        'formset': formset,
        'current_date': current_date,
    }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: It is both odd and in the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#changing-the-queryset